# How can I extend the message in Python gRPC?

Tags: python, grpc

I would like to know. How can I extend the message in Python gRPC? I mean, add an additional attribute to the message. For example. I have gRPC message named PID. I want to add the attribute to this message called process.  am trying to do it by adding this code in **`__init__.py`** but I get a eception

> AttributeError: 'PID' object has no attribute '__process'

```
def __init(self, *args, **kwargs):
if 'process' in kwargs:
    self.__process = kwargs['process']
    del kwargs['process']
self.__base_init(*args, **kwargs)



PID.__process = None
PID.__base_init = PID.__init__
PID.__init__ = __init
```

How I can add process attribute to gRPC message without editing .proto file.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, this is discouraged.

Protobuf files define a contract between clients and servers. Arbitrarily adding fields to messages in one implementation could break the contract.

If the process attribute should be part of the message (i.e. exposed to other clients and servers implementing the contract), then you should add a field to the protobuf message and regenerate code.

If you want to create an internal representation of the message in your code that serves as an implementation detail, then you should consider creating a new Python class and implementing methods that convert between it and the protoc-generated class.